# Unable to handle disabled element using selenium when there is no disabled attribute present

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

I have tried using isEnabled() but because its not a button and there is no disabled attribute present it always returns me true.

I have pasted code by inspecting, Please help me out in this,

9:29 AM

[Click on this to see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4om.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your class name update with the "disabled" text when its disabled. So you can try bellow method.

```
<<<<<<<<Imports>>>>>>>>

import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

<<<<<<<<Code>>>>>>>>
//get class value of the element
attribute = WebUI.getAttribute(findTestObject('<<Element Locator>>'), 'class')

boolean isSubstringPresent(String subString, String fullString) {
    return fullString.contains(subString)
}

//this will print true if the disabled text included in the class
println isSubstringPresent("disabled", attribute) // true
```

Mostly you can return correct boolean from above print. If it works use IF condition and plan your work.

If the above method not works I would like to suggest to run bellow Javascript in your browser and check its output.

```
document.getElementByClassName("sc-AxhUy irOhyl bigtix-session bigtix-session--available bigtix-session--disabled").disabled
```

If it works you can execute the same in your automation, however I'm not familiar with Katalon Studio and found that following code will work for you.

```
<<<<<<<<Imports>>>>>>>>

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor as JavascriptExecutor
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory

<<<<<<<<Code>>>>>>>>

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
JavascriptExecutor js = ((driver) as JavascriptExecutor)
String disabledState = js.executeScript(‘sc-AxhUy irOhyl bigtix-session bigtix-session--available bigtix-session--disabled").disabled’)
print(disabledState)
```

Comment: Do i need to import any package to execute the below code, document.getElementByClassName("sc-AxhUy irOhyl bigtix-session bigtix-session--available bigtix-session--disabled").disabled

Comment: This below code displays error as unexpected identifier, String disabledState = js.executeScript(‘sc-AxhUy irOhyl bigtix-session bigtix-session--available bigtix-session--disabled").disabled’)

Comment: **01 Answer**

for the first question: Open Browser (Chrome) > Open Developer Tools (F12) > Console > Paste bellow code there and hit enter and see its output.

`document.getElementByClassName("sc-AxhUy irOhyl bigtix-session bigtix-session--available bigtix-session--disabled").disabled`

**02 Answer**
Yes, you need to import JavascriptExecutor, but only if above JS gives you correct output in browser console.

**Preferred Way**
Please refer bellow article to check by class name contain "disable".
[link](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-get-attribute.html#example)

Comment: I have used this code, String message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(my xpath)).getAttribute('class')

println(message)

message2 = "disabled"

if(message.contains(message2)==true){

 println(" ")
 
} this worked for me.

Comment: Great that you fixed up the code. Exactly what I meant, thats the best way to check "disable" text in Class name.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your attached image, there is one attribute `aria-disabled = true`, You can always check against that attribute for checking whether it is enabled or disabled.

Comment: Pythonologist, There is a difference between the attributes `disabled` and `aria-disabled = true`

Comment: If i use aria-disabled =true, it returns true for disabled elements. It is not same as disabled attribute.